# Magento 1.9.3.2 Admin Panel - Config Error

Tags: php, magento, uncaught-exception

I have trying to access my configuration tab in the admin panel. The page dies and I get this;

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function initForm() on boolean in /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm() #1 /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction() #2 /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit') #3 /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #4 /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_C in /var/sites/a/alexwalton.me/public_html/dev/Magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php on line 92

Comment: First disable all third party extenison and then open your configuration.
After that enable extension one by one and check which extension create issues.